# Inter-Thread Communication (and libraries?)

Tags: c#, c++

If have I have a game engine that has multiple threads that all work with one scene graph, what are techniques to ensure everything is synchronized whenever that scene graph changes?

What kind of libraries are out there to help with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800383/what-is-the-difference-between-mutex-and-critical-section) for a list of availiable synchronization primitives. What you need to use depends on what your threads do. How many threads read the graph? How many modify the graph? Do they operate on the same part of the graph or on distinct parts? If you provide some more details, I can give further suggestions.