# Are Delphi simple types thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety

I declared two global variables:

```
var
  gIsRunning: Boolean = False;
  gLogCounter: Integer = 0;
```

These variables are written only in the main thread, and read in other threads. In this case, are these variables thread safe?

Comment: This question is actually impossible to answer in its current form. To answer it you would need to specify precisely what you [mean by threadsafe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx). You have some answers that think you mean, "Do my variables ever suffer from tearing?". You have an answer that deals with how to write to both variables atomically by using a lock. Both of these interpretations could be correct. But we can't tell because you have no specified enough information.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You are probably saying about atomic variables. Integer and Boolean variables are atomic. Booleans (bytes) are always atomic, integers (32-bits) are atomic because the compiler properly aligns them.

Atomicity means that any read or write operation is executed as a whole. If a thread A executes atomic write and a thread B atomic read of the same data at the same time, the data read by thread B is always consistent - it is impossible that some bits read by thread B are obtained from the current write operation and some bits from the previous write (by thread A)

But atomicity does not mean thread safety - you can easily write unsafe code with atomic variables. A variable itself cannot be threadsafe - only a code as a whole can be (or not) threadsafe.

Comment: Best summary comment I have seen on the issue!

Comment: Yes. Due to code reordering by the compiler or the CPU you can still write thread unsafe code with atomic variables. Or due to memory caching between CPUs or Cores.

Comment: I agree with your answer except for one thing. *Atomicity* is attribute of *operation*, not *variable* or *data type*. You can say, for example that increment is atomic, but you can't say integer is atomic. You can check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(programming)

Answer (score 15):

As long as there is only one thread that can write to them, then yes, they're thread safe.  The real problem with thread safety is two threads trying to modify a value at the same time, and you won't have that here.

If they were larger, like records or arrays, you might have issues with one thread trying to write a value, getting partway through, then getting context-switched and another thread reads partial (and therefore corrupt) data.  But for individual boolean (1 byte) and integer (4 byte) values, the compiler can automatically align them in such a way that the CPU can guarantee that all reads and writes to them are atomic, so that isn't a problem here.

Comment: @Mason, ok I agree with you answer, but accessing the global variables from multiples threads even if only are read can be considered a good design practice?

Comment: @RRUZ: Depends on who's doing the considering. I haven't seen a "Universal Objective Guide To Good Design Practices" anywhere, have you?  So I gave a technical answer, because that *can* be answered objectively.

Comment: No @Rruz, global variables aren't considered good design practice. Threads have nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Rob, I'm not talking about global variables. i just wanna point if the OP implement a system (application), based in global variables and multiples threads without use critical sections and some day another programmer or himself write a global variable inside a thread, the application will become unstable.

Comment: @RRUZ, I'd rather use a multiReadExclusiveWrite synchronizer...  Still, as far as performance goes,  if those vars can't be written to from the thread, it's only a waste. I believe entering critical section cause a switch from user-mode to kernel mode and back... which seems to be expensive on the performance side.

Comment: @Ken Bourassa: No, a switch to kernel mode occurs only in the case of contention (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800383/what-is-the-difference-between-mutex-and-critical-section/800422#800422).

Comment: Context switching is irrelevant. It's what happens on the memory bus that matters.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Context switching may not be irrelevant for those with performance in mind. And the other part of your comment - could you expand a bit so one could see what you're getting at?

Comment: @mghie I'm referring to Mason's mention of context switching in his answer. You don't need context switches to fall foul of tearing. You just need two threads sharing the memory bus.

Comment: Indeed. With today's machines it's much more fitting to think of multiple threads that are actually running concurrently than of the *possibility* of context switches.

Answer (score 13):

Simple types are "thread-safe" as long as they can be read in a single read (or written in a single write) from the memory. I'm not sure if it's defined by the CPU memory bus width, or their "integer" size (32 bits vs 64 bits cpu). Maybe someone else can clarify that part.

I know the read size nowaday is at least 32 bits. (Back in the Intel 286 days, it was only 8 bits at a time).

There is 1 thing to know about this though.  Even though it can read 32 bits at a time, it cannot start a read at just any address.  It needs to be a multiple of 32 bits (or 4 bytes). So, even an integer could be read in 2 subsequent reads if it's not aligned to 32 bits.  Thankfully, the compiler will align pretty much all fields to 32 bits (or even 64 bits) automatically.

There is an exception to this though, packed records are never aligned, and thus, even an integer in such a record wouldn't be thread safe.

Because of their size, int64 are not thread safe either. The same can be told about most floating types. (Except Single I believe).

Now, with all that in mind, there is some situation where you could actually write a global variable from multiple thread and still be "thread-safe".

For example,

```
var
  LastGoodValueTested : Integer

procedure TestValue(aiValue : Integer);
begin
  if ValueGood(aiValue) then
    LastGoodValue := aiValue
end;
```

here, you could call the routine TestValue from multiple threads and you wouldn't *corrupt* the LastGoodValueTested variables. It could happen that value that is written to the variable wouldn't be the very, very last though. (If a thread context switch happen between ValueGood(aiValue) and the assignation). So, depending on the needs, it may/may not be acceptable.

Now,

```
var     
  gLogCounter: Integer = 0;

procedure Log(S : string);
begin
  gLogCounter := gLogCounter + 1;
end;
```

Here, you can actually *corrupt* the counter because it's not a unary operation. You first read the variable.  Then add 1 to it.  Then you save it back. A thread context switch can happen in the middle of those operation. So that is a case that requires synchronization.

In that case, it could be rewritten to

```
procedure Log(S : string);
begin
  InterlockedIncrement(gLogCounter);
end;
```

I would think this is slightly faster than using critical sections... But I'm not sure.

Comment: +1 Best explanation so far. Directly assigning to a byte/integer is thread safe, doing *any* arithmetic and/or logic requires synchronization.

Comment: No, @Lieven, even doing arithmetic is OK, as long as only one thread ever does it. If all the other threads are readers, then there's nothing to worry about. The reader thread will either read the previous value of the variable, or the new value. There's no chance of reading some "in-between" value.

Comment: @Rob, I implied when multiple threads were involved as in the example given by @Ken. It would have been better to make that explicit *(as your comment now does :)*

Answer (score 8):

**No they are not are thread safe**, you must access such variables using for example a critical section, using [`InitializeCriticalSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`EnterCriticalSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`LeaveCriticalSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions

```
//declaration of your global variables 
var 
   MyCriticalSection: TRTLCriticalSection;
   gIsRunning: Boolean;
   gLogCounter: Integer;

//before the threads starts
InitializeCriticalSection(MyCriticalSection); 

//Now in your thread 
  EnterCriticalSection(MyCriticalSection); 
//Here you can make changes to your variables. 
  gIsRunning:=True;
  inc(gLogCounter); 
//End of protected block
LeaveCriticalSection(MyCriticalSection);
```

Comment: In what way is there a lack of thread-safety? Is there ever a chance one of those variables will receive an invalid value? Will a reader ever see an incorrect value?

Comment: @Rob my answer is in your another comment.

Comment: @Rob What could be wrong without locking is the order of reads and writes.

Comment: Not really, @David. Suppose it's important that a certain thread reads the variable before the other thread writes it. Without critical sections, either thread could win that race. *With* critical sections, the race is no longer about who accesses the variable first. Instead, it's about who enters the critical section first. Critical sections don't solve that problem. I don't think the question asked anything about the values of the *multiple* variables needing to be mutually consistent.

Comment: @Rob the question didn't specify enough details for anyone to answer in my view. You have assumed what you think the question is, but the reality is that OP has not asked a well-formed question. OP said nothing about how these variables are accessed. RRUZ has made one assumption. Others, including yourself, made different assumptions. All the answers make reasonable assumptions, but assumptions get you nowhere in software development.