# Multithreading: Character movement, drawing and socket handling

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I am making a small 2d online game and I currently have drawing, character moving and socket handling all done in the main thread. I think that it would be more convenient to create a own thread for those things, especially for the socket handling.

It's my first multi threaded application so should I basically just make the threads with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? I read that I just use mutexes or criticalsections to prevent two threads from accessing the data at the same time, which should I use?

Comment: What are you trying to ask? How to do threading? Or how to best handle data-sharing between threads? The confusion arises from the '?' after your statement of '...basically just make the threads with this?'. If it's about data-sharing, use Critical Sections as they don't go through Kernel mode and are faster than Mutexes.

Comment: Are you using C++11? (If so, you can use `std::thread` and friends to save you some grief and help with portability.) You should also read up on multithreading before you start, because a lot can go wrong in ways that are hard to debug! A critical section, btw, is an implementation of mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should create new threads with `CreateThread` method. Don't forget to create a message pump in each thread that is supposed to process messages (e.g. asynchronous socket handling).

As for mutexes vs. critical sections: critical sections would be more appropriate as you need to synchronize threads of only one process. For more details, see [What is the difference between mutex and critical section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800383/what-is-the-difference-between-mutex-and-critical-section) .

It's also convenient to use messages for communication between threads (see [PostThreadMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).