# Why do we need events to synchronize threads?

Tags: c, winapi, critical-section, thread-synchronization

If, for instance only 1 thread can access a `Critical Section` at a time, why do we need `Events` to synch 2 threads to read/write through it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some overlap in how they can be used, but there are also some unique features to both:

1. Critical sections cannot be used across processes, whereas events can.
2. A single manual-reset event can be used to release multiple threads at once. A critical section cannot.
3. Events are compatible with `WaitForSingleObject()` et al, whereas critical sections aren't.
4. A thread can wait on multiple events with `WaitForMultipleObjects[Ex]()`, but it can only wait for a single critical section (using a different API).

and so on.

They are not really in direct competition; it's best to think of them as being *complementary* to each other.

Mutexes are somewhere in the middle. For further discussion, see [What is the difference between mutex and critical section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800383/what-is-the-difference-between-mutex-and-critical-section)

Comment: I know they are complementary to each other, but I want to understand this specific thing. Why do we need events for CS? Isn't CS synching the threads already?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc: Well, you are asking a specific question without giving us any context. This makes it really hard to answer.

Comment: Hm, the context would be two threads using a CS to read and write alternatively. CS already blocks them alternatively, so why do we need Events for full synch?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Events allow you to block and wait until something happens, something a critical section does not. Often one waits for a shared resource that must be protected with e.g. a critical section.

Answer (score 0):

Events have a SetEvent function which lets it be used as a signal. When one thread has finished reading a file or filling a buffer, for example, it can SetEvent to get a different thread started on the next processing step for that data.