# Mutex for object creation

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, mutex

I'm creating an object like this:

```
       if (_cleaner == null)
        {
            _creation.WaitOne();
            try
            {
                if (_cleaner == null)
                {
                   //create object
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _creation.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
```

The reason i do the double check is because two threads can come simultaneously to the object creation and then I need obviously only one to create an  object. Is there a better way to do it?
So i dont have to check object existence twice?

Comment: That should be fine. That's optimistic pessimistic approach

Comment: why are using Mutex? do you need this for cross-process synchronization?

Comment: doesnt matter, you can use lock, but the performance is gonna be the same

Comment: actually because Mutex handles cross-process synchronization, it will be slightly slower than lock, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800383/what-is-the-difference-between-mutex-and-critical-section. Anyway, because you don't really need this you can use Lazy<T> which is cleaner and not error prone like double check locking.

Comment: can u eleborate on Lazy usage in this context, it might be the right direction

Comment: added some info as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `Lazy<T>`, it's cleaner syntax and less [error-prone than double check locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

It helps you create an object which is initialized only once when being first accessed ([lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)), I think that the syntax is quite self-explanatory, some usage examples are in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I'll cite the example:

```
class Customer
{
    private Lazy<Orders> _orders;
    public string CustomerID {get; private set;}
    public Customer(string id)
    {
        CustomerID = id;
        _orders = new Lazy<Orders>(() =>
        {
            // You can specify any additonal  
            // initialization steps here. 
            return new Orders(this.CustomerID);
        });
    }

    public Orders MyOrders
    {
        get
        {
            // Orders is created on first access here. 
            return _orders.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure if thats thread safe, what ThreadSafetyMode shall I use (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode(v=vs.110).aspx) and how the overhead is gonna affect performance?

Comment: You can go with the default (not passing ThreadSafetyMode to the constructor of Lazy<T>) which is ThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication and is thread-safe. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642329%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a framework(e.g. Unity) that has a lifetime manager to help manage your objects?
BTW, Unity does a lot more.

[Unity - Lifetime manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660872%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

Comment: Thats more like Singleton pattern, isnt it?

Comment: Unity lets you resolve objects while putting lifetimemanagers on each object(it also gives you the option for di and other stuff). 
The resolve function is thread safe, so you can basically define that class A will generate singleton objects and class B will generate HTTPContext objects. You can also build your own custom lifetime manager by just implementing a simple interface.
The usage is simple - you resolve you object by types.