# Critical section in mutex

Tags: mutex, critical-section

What is "*critical section*" in mutex? Explain with real time example.
I already read it in many article, but in that they explained about mutex 
and semaphore.
So I didn't understand what is critical section in mutex.

Using C language.

Comment: This is the first Google result for critical section in mutex: [What is the difference between mutex and critical section?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800383/what-is-the-difference-between-mutex-and-critical-section)

Comment: Edited the question a bit. You could read the description in the [tag:critical-section] tag I added, maybe that's enough to make you understand.

Comment: I ask real time example for critical section.